# How to download google chrome 59.0 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu-16.04

For the selenium, test-cases ran.

Initially, we are downloaded the chrome version 63.0

we get the following error :

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.10.0-42-generic x86_64)
```

please help me. I am a newbie to selenium testing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your title is about chrome 59.0, but your post is about chrome 63.0. A version of Chrome requires a specific version of chromedriver which is likely the reason of your exception. Have a look at the release notes: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 1):

From the error logs, it seems you are using **`Chrome v63.0`**, so you need to use the latest **`ChromeDriver v2.33`**

**Extract from ChromeDriver v2.33 Release Notes** :

> **`ChromeDriver v2.33 (2017-10-03)`** : Supports **`Chrome v60-62`**